# How do i execute 5 PHP scripts randomly between 30-120 seconds?

Tags: php, bash, random, cron

I have a problem i'am dealing with for a couple of days. I want to execute 5 PHP scripts that are located in 1 map on my ubuntu server.

I would like to have these 5 scripts randomly execute with a 15-60 seconds interval. So i get a situation like:

Execute random script (1-5).php -> Wait 15-60 sec -> Execute random script (1-5).php -> wait 15-60 sec etc....

I tried looking for solutions and i know it can be done but i can't find the right command. Should i use a cronjob only or use a bash script?

Comment: mybe this can help you using corn tab http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333197/running-a-script-via-cron-at-a-random-time-but-a-certain-number-of-times-per-da

Comment: Cron can only go every minute at least... So maybe you can execute a main script every 1 or 2 minutes by cron and make your subscripts execute their code using `sleep(15)` or `sleep(30)`

Comment: Write another PHP script that does exactly what you said (execute random script, wait random time, repeat). You can use `screen` to launch the script manually in a background session that doesn't close when log out or you can run it as a cron job. If you run it as a job take into consideration that a new instance will be launched at some moment in the future. You can, for example, make it exit after it ran for 59 minutes and configure cron to launch a new instance every hour.

Answer (score 0):

One possibillity:

```
<?php
    $scriptPath = "/some/path/";
    while (true) {
        $scriptId   = rand(1, 5);
        $sleepTime  = rand(15, 60);

        exec("nohup php ".$scriptPath . $scriptId . ".php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
        sleep($sleepTime);
    }
?>
```

Put the above code in a file called loopScript.php and kick off the code from the command line. Like so:

```
nohup php /path/to/script/loopScript.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To make the script run on reboot add the following to cron:

```
@reboot php /path/to/script/loopScript.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```